# grails - unsaved transient instance error

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm getting a transient instance error I can't fully solve (please see UPDATE at bottom).  I have the classes:

```
 class Order {
    static hasMany = [products: Product, transactions: MoneyTransaction]
    ...
    static constraints {
      transactions(minSize: 1) // order must have at least an authorization MoneyTransaction
          ...
    }
 }

 class MoneyTransaction {
     Order order 
       ...  
     static constraints = {
        order(nullable: true)
          ...
     }
 }
```

My controller code is

```
  MoneyTransaction mt = new MoneyTransaction(...)
      ...
  if (!mt.save(flush: true))  { log, render an error }  // no error occurs
  else { 
     println "mt saved, id: ${mt.id}"    // prints out mt id fine
     Order order = new Order(...)
         ...
     order.addToTransactions(mt)
     mt.order = order
     if (!order.save(flush: true)) { log, render an error } // no error occurs
     else {
       println "order saved, id: ${order.id}" // prints out order id fine

       // a method is called that creates a second MoneyTransaction that does the capture of
       // the previous authorization,  this method essentially does:
       MoneyTransaction capt = new MoneyTransaction(...)  // *** order is not set here ***
       if (! capt.save()) { log, render an error } // no error occurs
       println "capt saved, id: ${capt.id}"    // prints out capt id fine
       mt.relatedAction = "..."  // this is a MoneyTransaction String field              

       if (!mt.save(flush: true))  { log, render an error } // get error
```

Error is: *org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: momentum.Order*

I've looked at some of the other posts, and I don't have any findBy() used, and also I turned on logging for hibernate, but that doesn't reveal anything.  Any ideas of what the error is?

---

*UPDATE:  This error can be resolved by copying (setting) the order in capt before capt is saved above, namely adding the line:

```
 capt.order = mt.order
```

While I can do this before I save capt, I'm not clear why it is a problem if I do not set this.  If I don't set it, note capt saves fine, but the last/second save of mt produces the above error.

[Version Grails 1.3.7]

---

*UPDATE 2:   I removed the capt.save above, but I get the same mt save error.  This would appear to indicate that these two instances aren't related as far as the mt.save problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either way the problem is that when you call

```
mt.save()
```

by that time the contained Order object is in a transient unsaved state. Try saving it just before you try to save "mt".

```
order.save()
mt.order = order
mt.save()
```

Further guess (just a guess): It can be that you call a singleton transactional service method somewhere in between which will invalidate the current session and that is why the Order is in a transient state. I had some similar problem with Grails 1.3.7 before.